# Amazon Athena - Error Create Iceberg table

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, apache-iceberg

I used [this](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/9981f1a1-abdc-49b5-8387-cb01d238bb78/en-US/90-athena-acid/9011-prepare-data-acidtable) as a reference to create a Create statement that creates an Apache Iceberg table in Amazon Athena's Query Editor. Below.

```
CREATE TABLE iceberg_table (id int, data string, category string)
PARTITIONED BY (category, bucket(16, id))
LOCATION 's3://xxxxxxxx/iceberg_table/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
        'table_type' = 'ICEBERG',
        'format' = 'parquet',
        'write_target_data_file_size_bytes' = '536870912'
)
```

When I ran this, I got the following error.

```
Iceberg cannot found the requested entity
```

Also, when I ran Explain, I got the following message

```
line 2:1: mismatched input 'PARTITIONED'. Expecting: 'COMMENT', 'WITH', <EOF>
```

I think there is a problem with the Create statement I created.
I checked to see if extra spaces had been removed or if the quotes were incorrect, but could not find the cause.

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine for me. I'm using Athena with Engine v3, maybe that's the cause?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE iceberg_table (id int, data string, category string)
with (
        table_type = 'ICEBERG',
        partitioning = ARRAY(category, bucket(16, id))
        LOCATION = 's3://xxxxxxxx/iceberg_table/'
        format = 'parquet',
        write_target_data_file_size_bytes = '536870912'
)
```